# trouble splitting a string by line and colon

Tags: bash, unix

I know how to split a string by something such as a colon using IFS. However, with the script I am currently writing, I am running a command which returns something to me in the format of

```
Birthday      :      mon, date, year
First day     :      mon, date, year
```

I want to just get the date of the birthday. In order to do that, I am currently doing:

```
IFS=: read -r -a DATEARR <<< "$DATES"
echo "${DATEARR[1]}"
```

which would ideally print just the date that comes after "Birthday    :", but unfortunately nothing is printing. Any tips? Should I split this string by line as well?

The expected output I'd like is:
mon, date, year (corresponding to the Birthday field)

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @anubhava Just added that to the question, but its mon, date, year (corresponding to the birthday field)

Answer (score 0):

This is tailor made job for `awk` with a custom field separator:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]]*:[[:blank:]]*' '{print $2}' file

mon, date, year
mon, date, year
```

Note that with `IFS=:`, you will get a string left padded with spaces:

```
while IFS=: read -r -a DATEARR; do echo "${DATEARR[1]}"; done < file

      mon, date, year
      mon, date, year
```

You can use this to remove all the spaces:

```
while IFS=: read -r -a DATEARR; do echo "${DATEARR[1]//[[:blank:]]}"; done < file

mon,date,year
mon,date,year
```

Comment: How do I specify when using awk that I am using it for DATEARR?

Comment: You mean you want a BASH array even when using `awk`? You can do all the processing in awk itself.

Comment: If you really need BASH array variable then you may use my other solution using `while` loop.